# How to allow ABP to retrieve your computer ID in .NET MVC project

Tags: .net, api, abp

```
''2021-10-18 22:07:30.641 +02:00 [ERR] ABP-LIC-0013 - License exception: ABP-LIC-0023: An error occured while calling the license server! Cannot retrieve your computer ID! Contact to license@abp.io! [Architecture: X64 | Description: Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043 | FrameworkDescription: .NET Core 3.1.16 | Ex.Detail: Invalid class ]'''
```

This is what I have found in my log files after I've made a post request to my asp.net MVC API running off ABP framework

Please advise?

Comment: Have you thought about contacting license@abp.io?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not logged in, can you try again after you do?

```
abp login <username>                                  # Allows you to enter your password hidden

abp login <username> -p <password>                    # Specify the password as a parameter (password is visible)

abp login <username> --organization <organization>    # If you have multiple organizations, you need set your active organization

abp login <username> -p <password> -o <organization>  # You can enter both your password and organization in the same command
```

If the problem still persists, adding the output of the following command to your message and contacting license@abp.io may help you solve your problem faster.

```
abp login-info
```

I hope the information I have provided will be of use to you and your problem will be resolved soon.

References:

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI#login

Comment: I did try that  still got the same error ..i noticed that this error comes on when i try run a new instance in the Dbmigrator ( i am using mongodb which is deployed on aws instance )

Comment: Got it, so when running DbMigrator on AWS, are we sure there is `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` `Production`? I suspect you are trying to run it with the `Development` environment variable.